# parent class properties not getting applied to child anchor tag element

Tags: html, css

I was creating a navbar that has a class `top-navbar`. I included a few anchor tags in the `div`. When I used the CSS property `color: black` on the class, the anchor text was still blue(the original color). Instead when I used the property `color: black` on the anchor tag itself it works? Why doesn't it work on the class property, isn't it inherited by all elements that follow in the div with class = `nav-bar-items` The markup is as follows:

```html
<div class="top-navbar">
  <img class="logo-img" src="https://freesvg.org/download/47093">
  <div class="nav-bar-items">
    <a href="https://xyz.info/about">about</a>
    <a href="https://xyz.info/notes">notes</a>
    <a href="htts://xyz.info/contact">contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of solution you already know how to turn your anchor text black. 
But your question was why is is not inheriting? Here is my explanation of why it didn't work for you for provided css.

**CSS Specificity**

Rule to calculate specificity is defined by `{style, ids, [classes, attributes and pseudo-classes], [elements and pseudo-elements] }`

If we calculate the specificity of selectors on anchor tag, we will have the answer.

`a:-webkit-any-link` (User Agent) -> 0011 (1 for pseudo-classes and 1
       for element)

`.top-navbar` -> 0010

So clearly here user agent styling wins and take over so the color is still blue, check below snapshot.

[image]

Reference to read more about it -

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

https://specificity.keegan.st/

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know why and I am pretty sure it was already answered here on SO, but why even bother with it when you can just target your links? Just some Examples, there's even more ways:

```
.nav-bar-items a {
    color:red;
  }

.nav-bar-items > *{
    color:red;
  }
```

Read about selectors: 
[CSS_Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tags are getting browser default styling and need something more specific to override it:

```
.nav-bar-items a {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tags are loaded with default styling properties. There are different methods to customize.

```
1. By using inheritance

        .nav-bar-items > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
};


 2. override

        .nav-bar-items a {
        color:color-name;
      };

 3. This one is only, if your parent class has a single child <a> tag then you can use it. 

        a:only-child {
        color: color-name;
      };
```